# Laravel eloquent max function does not give correct value greater than 99,999

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
App\Employee::max('salary');
```

does not give max value if salary is greater than 99,999. Salary column type is string because salary column can contain salary amount or a text info.

What I can do to solve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the column type of salary ?

Comment: Why would the column for a number be a string? This makes zero sense and is probably the cause of your problem here. `max` can only work on one type of data at a time. Having a salary of `"lots"` is going to wreck everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but `max` SQL function can work only with numeric types. Try to switch from `VARCHAR` to `FLOAT`.

Comment: For a salary `INT` makes more sense. If someone is actually being paid fractional units of currency, `DECIMAL` with fixed places is best. Using `FLOAT` is how you end up in a world of hurt due to floating-point oddness.

Comment: Salary column can contain salary amount or a message like 'This employee is no longer working here.'. That's why I used string to store either salary or a message.

Comment: That's not good practice at all, I would rather make the salary column nullable and set to NULL if employee no longer has a salary and add a separate column for working status / additional remarks.

Comment: Or just return NULL from model and check it in controller or view so you can output what ever message you want. Consider about having INT nullable field for that. ( @Afraz )

Comment: I have changed its type to float and will handle other info in seperate column.Thanks